# Running keycloak along with postgres db via docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I currently have a docker compose file which sets up a psql database and runs around 80 sql files to create the relations for my application. What I want to do now is add a keycloak layer to the application. I'm trying to do this via the compose file as well but I keep getting an error saying that one of my relation already exists. What I think is happening is that when I keycloak service is running its trying to overwrite the database and I don't want that to happen. I'm not sure how to fix this, I've tried a bunch of other methods found online but none of them work.

Here is my compose file (removing some of the sql scripts to make it simpler):

```
---
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    environment:
    # add multiple schemas
      # POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: ${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE},${POSTGRESQL_KEYCLOAK_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
      # POSTGRES_KEYCLOAK_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_KEYCLOAK_USER}
      # POSTGRES_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      # POSTGRES_DB2: ${POSTGRESQL_KEYCLOAK_DATABASE}
    hostname: local
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /pgdata
      - ./sql/access_attempt.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/A.sql
      - ./sql/bceid.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/B.sql
      - ./sql/lookup_activitytype.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/C.sql
      - ./sql/lookup_gender_pronoun.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/D.sql
      - ./sql/client.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/E.sql
     
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - db-keycloak

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    entrypoint:
      - "sh"
      - "-c"
      - "npm i && npm run start"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      POSTGRESQL_HOST: ${POSTGRESQL_HOST}
      POSTGRESQL_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: ${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s
    hostname: backend
    image: node:14
    links:
      - database
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app:z
      - /app/node_modules
    working_dir: "/app"

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    container_name: keycloak-service
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: database
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_USER:  ${POSTGRESQL_KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "28080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always
    links: 
      - database
    networks:
      - db-keycloak

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    entrypoint:
      - "sh"
      - "-c"
      - "npm i && npm run start"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      BACKEND_URL: backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s
    hostname: frontend
    image: node:14
    links:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app:z
      - /app/node_modules
    working_dir: "/app"

networks:
  db-keycloak:
```

And here is the error:

```
18:05:57,142 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Change Set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com failed.  Error: ERROR: relation "client" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.CLIENT (DTYPE VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ALLOWED_CLAIMS_MASK BIGINT, ENABLED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, FULL_SCOPE_ALLOWED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(255), NOT_BEFORE INT, PUBLIC_CLIENT BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, SECRET VARCHAR(255), BASE_URL VARCHAR(255), BEARER_ONLY BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, MANAGEMENT_URL VARCHAR(255), SURROGATE_AUTH_REQUIRED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, DIRECT_GRANTS_ONLY BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, REALM_ID VARCHAR(36))]
18:05:57,142 ERROR 
[org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Error has occurred while updating the database: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:
         Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "client" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.CLIENT (DTYPE VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ALLOWED_CLAIMS_MASK BIGINT, ENABLED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, FULL_SCOPE_ALLOWED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(255), NOT_BEFORE INT, PUBLIC_CLIENT BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, SECRET VARCHAR(255), BASE_URL VARCHAR(255), BEARER_ONLY BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, MANAGEMENT_URL VARCHAR(255), SURROGATE_AUTH_REQUIRED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, DIRECT_GRANTS_ONLY BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, REALM_ID VARCHAR(36))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to error your existing postgres database already have table/relation named `client`. But Keycloak is trying to create `client` table of its own which is causing this error.

To fix this issue, I would suggest to use two different postgres `databases/schemas`, one for your application and other for keycloak instance.

Comment: Hey @Abhijeet, you're correct. Seems like keycloak is trying to create its own client table. I know I can create a new service for the keycloak db but I'm trying to figure out how to add a new schema to the existing one. This would save me the hassle of having another service just for keycloak and having multiple schemas will solve the problem of the same table being created.